# TFS mapping the same for an entire development team

Tags: tfs, mapping

We're using TFS for our source control and we're facing the following problem.  Everybody has mapped their projects differently.  This is causing builds to break(as person1 has project/file references different than person2).  Currently we pass around a piece of paper with all the mapping printed out, and it seems a bit antiquated.

So my question(s) is:

Where does VS store the mappings for each user?

Is there a way to enforce everyone to have the same mappings(or pass out a file that will map everyone the same)?

Comment: If different mappings are breaking your builds, the problem isn't the mapping it is your project/solution structure.

Comment: You're probably right, but there isn't anything I can do about that(management decision).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mappings are stored in TFS and on the client, but they're not 'enforceable'. What you can do is create a WorkspaceTemplate. This option is only available from the command line (by default). See [`tf.exe workspace /new /template`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y901w7se%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

But the [Team Foundation Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f) add this feature to the Team Utilities page of team explorer:
[image: Team Utilities]

Then you can instruct your team members to use the WorkspaceTemplate when setting up their workspaces.

You can also [copy/paste the workspace definition to notepad and copy/paste it back into Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138514.aspx#copy_paste) (quite nifty).

You could also create a small Workspace Analyzer to find the broken workspaces. The TFS Object Model can be used to query all workspaces that are stored on a TFS server.

Comment: Thanks, I think this will help.